# German Emergency Visa

Tags: visa-refusals, business-travel, schengen-visas

I am a freelancer & have been working with a German company for the last 5 years with a few successful projects.

This January we have several more projects that I have to finalize with the company, so I have to go Germany for 30 days to do this and make future plans with the existing team.

I have already applied for a business visa & have been refused for this reason:

> Your intention to leave the territory of the member states before the expiry of the visa could not be ascertained.

I am going to appeal tomorrow. However, do you know any easy solution to get a quick visa as I have to make the deal by the end of January, otherwise I will lose the projects?

My client is ready to make any support for quick turnaround. Can you guys please suggest what should I do? If my client came to Bangladesh, would this work or are there any other solutions to go to Germany?

Comment: Please post a photo of the refusal letter with your personal information blanked out. And yes, you should consider having your client visit you instead because they should be able to more easily than the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

- *If* your client knows you well and if he is willing to take the risk, he could sign a Verpflichtungserklärung. This is a promise to reimburse the German state for any costs if you should overstay, either intentionally or unintentionally. (Obviously that is a serious financial risk for them.) Having a Verpflichtungserklärung does not guarantee a visa, but it helps.
- You should consider if you appear as an overstay risk and what you can do to change this perception. A freelancer, relatively young, living in Bangladesh, that *looks* bad. Did you get any Schengen visas in the past? What changed with this application? So remember to mention any factors in your favor. Do you have other clients, in Bangladesh or elsewhere outside Schengen? Is your freelance business registered as a company?

Comment: Thanks, Man :) I am going to talk to my client about the Verpflichtungserklärung :)

Unfortunately, I didn't get any Schengen Visa Past 
Yes I have registered company & I have few American client as well 
& i have a fixed job on Geneva, Switzerland & there i work remotely

Comment: @Codexpart, so if you were to immigrate to the Schengen area, you'd already have a job lined up. Sounds like you'd want to immigrate if you could. Have you considered to come on a high-skilled immigrant track? Then your intention to leave is no issue. Ask on Expatriates SE.